# Problem upgrading Grails from 3.3.2 to 3.3.9: Exeption on startup "Unable to create initial connections of pool" due to H2 upgrade

Tags: grails, h2

I get the following error on startup after I upgraded from GRAILS 3.3.2 to 3.3.9:

> org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool : Unable to create initial connections of pool.
>   org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Scale($"10") must not be bigger than precision({1});

```
({1}); SQL statement:
CREATE CACHED TABLE PUBLIC.GAME(
ID BIGINT DEFAULT (NEXT VALUE FOR PUBLIC.SYSTEM_SEQUENCE_6AFE1F30_C0FB_47AD_B2B5_FD6A519957AE) NOT NULL NULL_TO_DEFAULT SEQUENCE PUBLIC.SYSTEM_SEQUENCE_6AFE1F30_C0FB_47AD_B2B5_FD6A519957AE SELECTIVITY 100,
VERSION BIGINT NOT NULL SELECTIVITY 3,        
...
FINALROI DOUBLE SELECTIVITY 76,
STATUS VARCHAR DEFAULT 'FINISHED' NOT NULL SELECTIVITY 1
) [90051-197]
```

This problem only occurs when using an existing H2 database (that contains a lot of data). I tested with setting **dbCreate: create ** and everything works fine then. I also did a comparison of the schema created and it was identical to the one in my actual DB.

I also tested that the break happens with GRAILS 3.3.5. I went though the content of the release and could find nothing that would cause this behavior.

Could someone point me in the right direction? Is there a problem with the data in my database (somehow invalid inserts has happened or something) or is this caused by something else.

**EDIT**

Has to do with the H2 upgrade to version 1.4.197. Easy workaround is do downgrade by setting the previous version in build.gradle

```
runtime "com.h2database:h2:1.4.196"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was bad sql which was was not properly validated due to a bug in earlier H2 versions. For some reason the schema contained a statement, where `scale > precision`:

```
_TIME TIMESTAMP(23, 10)
```

Fixed it with a DB conversion.